# Is there any way to make Outlook 2011 automatically run all rules?

Tags: automation, microsoft-outlook-2011, microsoft-office-2011

I'm using Outlook 2011, coming form Gmail, and want to have it automatically run all rules. I'd prefer if I can set triggers like *"once a minute"* or *"when an email arrives"* or *"when email category changes"*. **Is this possible?** I'm not against using scripts.